# div's have to much space

Tags: css, html, space

I have a line of `divs`, but half of them should only be lines to connect the other `divs`. Now even though I set the `margin` to 0px, there is still a little bis space left between those `divs`. But I decide to roll with it, since it looks good. But now I have the problem that this space isn't there for `divs` printed with php. Why is that and how can I fix it? I tried adding `margin` but that won't change anything.

Here's the code I have:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/AI28E7

As you can see it begins with the fifth `div`, which is also the first to be printed using php.

Comment: PHP does nothing to show margins in divs, it simply generates html markup exactly as you print it, and it's up to the browser to render it according to any styles that you have set in your generated markup and any css that applies.... work out how you woud get the appearance you need as plain html markup, then get php to output that markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with whitespace. You actually don't have any margins on your dividers or your boxes. Set either one to have margin left and right.

```
.vert {
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Also, inline-block elements will show whitespace before and after them. You could set the div's back to display as block and float them left, along with the dividers. You will have to change the vert style to be margin-top instead of margin-bottom though.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. But how can I now add another row at the bottom to gave a grid? A <br> is not enough and two are too much.